# Поиск решения для тестирования поведения приложения при сетевых сбоях и ошибках

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, тестирование, поиск-программ

У меня есть приложение, которое соединено с сервером по [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket). И сервер, и приложение следят за состоянием соединения, приложение умеет реконнектиться при потере соединения. На клиенте используется [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) v7.3.1.

При каком-то типе сетевого сбоя кто-то из пары сервер-клиент начинает вести себя не так, как ожидается (то ли на сервере не умирает старое соединение и при этом выполняется создание нового, то ли на клиенте одновременно начинают существовать 2 соединения).

Нужна программа или npm-пакет (или какой-то аддон к https-proxy-agent, socks-proxy-agent), через которую я бы пропустил трафик приложения и которая бы создавала бы разные типы сетевых сбоев (в идеале - от серий быстрых реконнектов и вплоть до смены внешнего ip-адреса). Или нужно пояснение какой подход применить, чтобы самому инициировать сетевые сбои и ошибки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### netem (tc)

Попробуйте пакет [netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem). На странице проекта есть примеры использования. Есть deb-пакет.

Программа может:

- сетевые задержки
- потеря, дублирование, перестановка порядка пакетов
- повреждение пакетов

### pumba

Инструмент для **докер-контейнеров**. [Репо на GitHub](https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba).

- краш-тест - вырубает отдельные контейнеры
- эмуляция сетевых сбоев (на основе netem)
- стресс-тестирование: CPU, память, файловая система, io и прочее

### saboteur

[Страница проекта](https://github.com/tomakehurst/saboteur). Есть CLI-вариант управления, а также **можно управлять по HTTP**:

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "name": "packet-loss-to-app-server", "type": "PACKET_LOSS", "direction": "IN", "to_port": 8080, "probability": 0.2, "correlation": 25 }' http://192.168.2.11:6660/
```

Написана на питоне. Возможности:

- полная блокировка порта
- задержки
- потеря пакетов

### dummynet (ipfw)

[Домашняя страница с примерами использования](http://info.iet.unipi.it/%7Eluigi/dummynet/). Собирается из сорцов.

Программа ограничивает скорость сети в разных режимах. Остальные возможности также схожи с предыдущими программами.

### Армия обезьян

[Simian Army](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki) состоит из трех "обезьян хаоса", которые ломают части работающей системы. Разработано Netflix. Может также пригодиться, но похоже что заточено под AWS.

Comment: @nörbörnën я подумал, может кто-то уже сделал докер образ для этого дела, и ... да. Добавил в список.

Comment: прекрасный ответ, спасибо за информацию! так как других ответов нет, приму его

Comment: кстати, этим программам ведь пофик шифрованный/нешифрованный трафик?

Comment: @nörbörnën они работают на уровне TCP/IP, а шифрование происходит по модели OSI на более высоком уровне. Поэтому - пофиг. И еще: есть инструменты для отладки, подмены шифрованного трафика, то есть работают как MITM-прокси. Конкретные название не приведу, но многие из них стоят в Kali linux, вот [списочек](https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing)

Answer (score 2):

Решение для [macos](/questions/tagged/macos):

Инструмент Network Link Conditioner можно найти в пакете “Additional Tools for Xcode”. Вы можете скачать его со страницы [Загрузки для разработчиков Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools).

Включение Network Link Conditioner изменяет сетевую среду в масштабе всей системы в соответствии с выбранной конфигурацией, ограничивая пропускную способность uplink or download bandwidth, latency, and rate of packet loss.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете выбрать одну из следующих предустановок:

- 100% Loss
- 3G
- DSL
- EDGE
- High Latency DNS
- LTE
- Very Bad Network
- WiFi
- WiFi 802.11ac

… Или создайте свой собственный в соответствии с вашими требованиями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://superuser.com/a/314968/1219016) от участника [@Gaff](https://superuser.com/users/73637/gaff) и статьи [Network Link Conditioner](https://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Я вынес в отдельный ответ, как можно протестировать веб-сокеты на предмет отказоустойчивости по сценарию. Для этого есть npm пакет artillery. На странице пакета есть [описание его возможностей](https://www.npmjs.com/package/artillery).

Вот что особенно интересно:

- можно написать собственные сценарии поведения, в несколько шагов
- нагрузочное и функциональное тестирование

Как бы я это использовал:

1. написал сценарий типичного подключения к ws и обмен типичными данными
2. настроил на непрерывное выполнение этого сценария в несколько потоков (штатная возможность artillery) на протяжении минуты
3. написал тест на nodejs (mocha или что-то посовременней), который бы асинхронно запускал `artillery run ...`, и одновременно - сетевые сбои через одну из программ в моем [первом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1183589/287469), например `netem`. Также на одну минуту
4. сбор и анализ метрик, которые пишет artillery

Сценарий для тестирования можно написать по этому примеру из [этой статьи](https://ma.ttias.be/benchmarking-websocket-server-performance-with-artillery/)

```
config:
  target: "wss://socket.ohdear.app/app/2420b144fceaca7df5a5?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false"
  phases:
    - duration: 60  # Test for 60 seconds
      arrivalRate: 10 # Every second, add 10 users
      rampTo: 100 # And ramp it up to 100 users in total over the 60s period
      name: "Ramping up the load"
    - duration: 120 # Then resume the load test for 120s
      arrivalRate: 100 # With those 100 users we ramped up to in the first phase
      rampTo: 100 # And keep it steady at 100 users
      name: "Pushing a constant load"
scenarios:
  - engine: "ws"
    flow:
      - send: '{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"public"}}'  # Subscribe to the public channel
      - think: 15 # Every connection will remain open for 15s
```