# Как можно эмулировать выдергивание LAN-кабеля?

Tags: c#, lan, c#-8.0

Мне необходимо чтобы запросы от приложения пытались получить ответ, но было лишь ожидание, как было бы если кабель LAN был не подключен. Соответственно, нужен метод для эмулирования отключения Ethernet'а, т.е. не подходит метод с отключением адаптера, метод с выключением DHCP и метод с блокировкой пакетов тоже.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151937/discussion-on-question-by-onanistcmon-----lan-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск решения для тестирования поведения приложения при сетевых сбоях и ошибках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183550/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой план: на одном компе выдернуть кабель и посмотреть, как это отразится на работе, какие ошибки будет выдавать приложение. Попробовать другие способы, например (не вижу здесь), изменить адрес подсети в настройках протокола, чтобы лишить комп связи. Может, какой-то из подобных вариантов будет давать такую же ошибку, как и отключение кабеля. Его и использовать для имитации обрыва связи.

А вообще, непонятно. Что за проблема провести испытания и отладку на одном компьютере?